# URLConnection or HTTPClient for backgroung processing?

Tags: android, httpclient, urlconnection

I want to build an app which will transmit data(Long, lat, timestamp and SSID) every 60 seconds to the server in the background. The data will stored in the  in the database and in case of request it will send response back to the user. Which one is more convenient for this kin of processing HTTPConnection or HTTPClient?
which programmatically steps shall I take in consideration to make my Server  diel with multiple clients?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: learn a little bit programming then build your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPClient as provided in Android is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) since Version 5.1 (API level 22), because they included a pre-release version of HTTPClient 4.0 when they created Android.

I'd suggest to use the URLConnection API to be save.

Alternatively you could include your own HTTPClient package, but that may not be that easy because Android already has its own version.